# Arrow function isn't getting the value of a object property

Tags: javascript, object, arrow-functions

I'm trying to use a arrow function inside of a JS object, but it isn't getting the value of a object property. However, if I use a traditional function expression, it works properly.

Here's an example, first using a arrow function:

```
const obj = {
    name: "StackOveflow",
    simpleMethod: () => `Hello, ${this.name}!`
};

console.log(obj.simpleMethod());
```

The **output** is:

```
Hello, undefined!
```

Now using a traditional function expression:

```
const obj = {
    name: "StackOveflow",
    simpleMethod: function () {
        return `Hello, ${this.name}!`
    }
};

console.log(obj.simpleMethod());
```

The **output** is:

```
Hello, StackOveflow!
```

Why the arrow function doesn't get the name of the property?

Was expecting that the arrow function would get the value of the property, working in the same way as the traditional function expression

Comment: You'll need to use a tradition function, I believe, as arrow functions don't have their own bindings to `this`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions